# data from every table in last minute

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Super quick one

I am building a synchronisation application (for an off-line web app)

I am struggling with the best way to make it efficient.

I have 28 tables - potentially this could be 50 or even 100 in the future.

My synchronisation routine simply asks for all data since a certain timstamp (simplified explanation)

The problem I have is how make this efficient for repeat polling.

**NO SOCKETS - HAS TO WORK ie7**

Lets say table 1 and table 7 are updated.

When I ask for updates I need to be able to return the new data for table 1 and 7 - but without having to check every table!

I contemplated having a 'logs' table that has every transaction simplified (table, ID(of that table), timestamp) and then query the relevant tables - but I am wondering if there is an even better way?

I have had a good look through SO and know how to run the queries etc. - just missing the step of 'how to find data from every table since a date/time'

If I have missed a SO answer please let me know - I try not to duplicate!

Comment: This sounds like a problem of poor design

Comment: and how is that? I have an off-line application and it needs to operate independently of the server - and then sync to the server whenenver there is a connection - how could the design be improved?

Comment: Because you don't whether you have 50 tables or 100. You should know, and it shouldn't change (much) - and it probably shouldn't be anywhere near 100 (or 50) (or even 28)

Comment: lol - at the moment I have 28 tables - what happens if I add a chat feature to the application, or a documents library, or a forum? I am expected to know how many tables i need as the project evolves> Lets forget furutre tables - I have 28 - do you have anything constructive to deal with my current problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to cache the results somewhere else. If you have a high load, memcached might be a good idea. But first, try getting the results you want every x seconds or every x minutes, and save the results to disk somewhere. Then, just serve that file from disk to the client when they request it. That way, you move some load from the database to the web server.

Comment: I contemplated this - but then what happens when someone requests data and I need the data from the last 3 hours say? That is a lot of file reads! I will be polling this every 1-2 seconds so would I make a file / minute and write extra info to it or one / second or one for every database write?

Comment: Do you really need the data from the last seconds? Or is a 15 second cache good enough? If not, then maybe you should opt for either a memory table in MySQL storing the latest data, or maybe have a look at something like memcached.

Comment: technically there are only 2 parts that would need to be nearly 'live' - the rest could be 15 seconds I suppose as I am liking this solution - and the system operates exclusively with JSON for data trasnport anyway. So how would I set this up correctly - for every database operation write the data to a file - then just see via date time whether to write to an existing file or a new file -> final question with this -> will this not end up slower if say 500 trans / sec are happening -> surely the log will then be the bottleneck? Thanks for help so far

Comment: If you're changing the cache all the time, yes. But if you just prepare all the data, and store exactly the same data you send back in a file on disk or in memory for 15 seconds. Then, if the file in memory is less than 15 seconds old, you just send that one back - without doing any sql queries of any kind. Basically you're delivering static content, except for every 15 seconds when you update the cache.

Comment: thanks - I will try and see how best to implement this with the suggestions you gave. +1 and accepted.